# Postgresql, Python - Editing date/time exporting it and inserting it to SQL

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm creating a car parking system, and what I need is:

- Editing car registration date/time, and car after some time when paying for it.
  So let's say that one hour is 5$, and what I need is to somehow get the time correctly from sql to application. Let's say that John registered his car with "MDL512" Numbers at 2019/09/04 17:00:00, John came back after 5 hours to get his car out of parking, and he has to pay for the parking. One hour is 5$, so we do the math 5$ * 5 hours = 25$. And also when John registered his car numbers the application inserted the car numbers into SQL, CARNUM column for example. So what I need is to : Somehow get the time when John wants to pay, and calculate it in hours (5 hours as John registered his car) from I think SQL or application. It should work somehow as this.Paying_time - Registration_time = Parking_Time_After_Registration.
- Getting the car number by input, so that's for example - HAK008.

  while Registration:
      car_numb = input("Input car number:")

  ```
  if car_numb_re.match(car_numb) and car_numb.isupper():
      # matches!
      print("Match'ES")
      break
  elif car_numb.islower():
      print("Wrong number format. Should be (ABC123)!")
      continue
  ```
- The time I'm using when car registration was made - `Reg_Tikslus_Laikas = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.localtime())`

Comment: What exactly is the question that you want to ask?

Comment: Read the first row.

Comment: Editing car registration date/time